# Combining multiple custom QGIS plugins into one plugin?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, xml

I have built multiple individual QGIS plugins for my team using the QGIS Python plugin builder. Actually, my plugins are hosted on a private repository I made and the users can install them individually by adding the XML the repository to their Plugin manager settings.

Is there a simple way to make an entry in the repository XML or something else so that all my plugins are getting installed together?